# React this.state.bottles.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have this React component that is going to list bottles of alcohol. I'm running into an issue where, although my components state gets returned, I am still not able to map over it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Bottles extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { bottles: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bottles`)
      .then(res => {
        const bottles = res.data;
        this.setState({ bottles });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout css={{ padding: 0 }} pageTitle="Bottles">
        <ul>
          { console.log(this.state.bottles) }
          { this.state.bottles.map(bottle => <li>{bottle.id}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

I have a console log in the render and it seems to render two different items. My guess is the state before the axios request is completed, maybe? But i'm not sure how to correct for this.

If I inspect my console I see two things being output...

```
[]
{data: Array(20)}
```

Can anybody help me figure out what is going on here? Little confused here.

Comment: Two hypotheses I have are 1. the response need to be unwrapped one more level - to do this, change `const bottles = res.data` to  `const bottles = res.data.data` or 2. there is not id for each bottle item so it's an empty element

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your API is not returning an array as you may have expected, but an object, the one you see in the console. So just change:
`const bottles = res.data;` to `const bottles = res.data.data;` and it should work.

Comment: Ah there we go. Much appreciated. Thank you, Christian.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting `{data: Array(20)}` in logging `this.state.bottles`, that means you are looping over an object instead of an array.

In `componentDidMount` you need to set `res.data.data` instead of `res.data`, something like,

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bottles`)
      .then(res => {
        const bottles = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ bottles });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

I hope this resolves the issue.